# Exception loading lifecycle module [user]; [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: StartupListener.java]

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

Хочу создать класс, который будет стартовать вместе с сервером `glassfish`, при его запуске. Я создал класс `StartupListener`:

```java
public class StartupListener implements LifecycleListener {

     public void handleEvent(LifecycleEvent event) throws ServerLifecycleException {

            if (LifecycleEvent.STARTUP_EVENT == event.getEventType()) {
                MessageReceiver receiver = new MessageReceiver();
            }       
     }
}
```

`MessageReceiver` - класс который будет "слушать" очередь `TestQueue` и будет выводить то текстовое сообщение, которое пришло туда:

```java
public class MessageReceiver implements MessageListener {
    /*@Resource(name = "MyTestConnectionFactory")
    ConnectionFactory factory;
    @Resource(name = "MyJMSTestQueue")
    Queue ioQueue;*/
    MessageReceiver(){
        Session session = null;
        Connection connection = null;
        ConnectionFactory factory = null;

        try{
            Context jndiContext = new InitialContext();

            factory = (ConnectionFactory)jndiContext.lookup("MyTestConnectionFactory");
            Queue ioQueue = (Queue)jndiContext.lookup("MyJMSTestQueue");

            connection = factory.createConnection();
            connection.start();

            session = connection.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

            MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(ioQueue);
            consumer.setMessageListener(this);


            System.out.println("Listening to the Test Queue..");
            Thread.sleep(3000);

            }catch(JMSException e1){
                System.out.println("Error: " + e1.getMessage());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("InterruptedException: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.out.println("NamingException: " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                try{
                    session.close();
                    connection.close();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Can't close JMS connection/session " + e.getMessage());
                }

            }


    }
    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String msgText;
        try{
            if (arg0 instanceof TextMessage){
                msgText = ((TextMessage) arg0).getText();
                System.out.println("Got from the queue: " + msgText);
            }else{
                System.out.println("Got a non-text message");
            }
        }
        catch (JMSException e){
            System.out.println("Error while consuming a message: " +
        e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

Я создал lifecycle module с помощью `asadmin`, и создал `jar file` в `eclipse`. Поместил его в папку `domain1/lib`, но `glassfish` его не находит. Я думаю проблема в том, что я неправильно создал `jar-file`. Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно сконфигурировать `jar file` для класса `StartupListener`.

Comment: Судя по ошибке, вы где-то в настройках GlassFish-а указали вместо имени класса `StartupListener` имя файла с исходником класса `StartupListener.java`.

Comment: Я создал jar file тоже с именем StartupListener)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это просто....

Я указал при создании `lifecycle module` название `StartupListener.java`, а не просто `StartupListener`.

Такую простую ошибку допустил....